# Does Phonegap/Cordova make a web app faster?

Tags: cordova

I've searched around but haven't found anything that that specifically answers this question.

I've never created a hybrid app before so I was curious if importing my web app into phonegap/cordova would increase the performance?

Comment: No, in fact it's usually slower than opening the website in Safari (iOS) or Chrome (Android). If you use Chrome on iOS, then the speed should be the same as Chrome on iOS is just a webview. On android you can use crosswalk plugin that will switch your webview to a chromium based one and should be as performant as Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of Phonegap / Cordova is not to improve performance but to allow the application access to device functionalities that a script running in the browser cannot access so easily (unlimited local storage, camera, gps, ...). It also allows an app to run when the device is not connected to the network.

Considering performance, I have found that running a cordova app on Android is actually slower than running the same script in a chrome browser on the device. The reason is that the Cordova app uses a different browser engine (with slower script performance) than the chrome app.